# Why has storyboard gone transparent for all my apps, in Xcode 8 + 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I don't know what I did, but in every workspace I open, on Xcode 8 or 9,the view controllers are totally transparent. I can see the segue lines through them. I can't see my content at all, but it is there if I click on it, and is there in the simulator too. What did I do? How can I fix it? thank you please.

[This is what controllers look like now, for any project that I open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6bXo.png)

Comment: May be you have support for any particular device and you are not checking for that.

Comment: I've tried viewing as different devices, no change. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @SimeonSense it is normal issue you have given clear color in attribute inspector i have posted solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have given background color to clear see in below image
'[image]

If my understanding is correct, you just need to click on your view controller's view, for instance, your LoginViewController's view. That's the 1st view in your controller's views hierarchy. Then in the attributes inspector, on your screen's right side, you can set the view's background colour to 'white colour'. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I've tried that on every view, in the project I was building when the problem first occurred. no change, but the storyboard is taking a very long time to load, although I've only got 7 view controllers, mostly empty.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jaydeep, I deleted Xcode and reinstalled it, now everything is fine.